# Could Pre-image theorem be generalized to Hilbert Manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, differential-topology, banach-spaces

$f:M\to N$ is a smooth map between manifolds of dimensions $m\geq n$. If $y\in N$ is a regular value, then the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m-n$ or $\emptyset$.

Could the Pre-image theorem be generalized to Hilbert space or other infinite dimensional spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corollary 5.8 (page 17) in "[Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/Lang%20S.%20Introduction%20to%20Differentiable%20Manifolds%20(ISBN%200387954775)(Springer,%202002)(263s)_MDdg_.pdf)" by S.Lang. You do not even need Banach manifolds for this, just manifolds modeled on topological vector spaces.  This corollary implies that each regular level set $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth submanifold of the same codimension  as the dimension of the target manifold.

Comment: Can you check the number of the Corollary? And maybe specify chapter? Can't find it.

Comment: @positrón0802: See the edit; initially I mistyped 4.8 instead of 5.8.